# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 1610

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am getting an error in Ajax as

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 1610`

jQuery call for ajax json is as

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    data: "q=" +value,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
       if(data.results.length === 0){
         console.log("No Data");
       }else{
         for (var i in data.results) {
            var name = data.results[i].name;
            alert(name);
         }
       }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        alert(err.Message);
    }
});
```

JSON from server is

```
{
"results": [

{
    "id": " 14914",
  "asd" : "25263",
    "name": "asd ",
  "label":"ad ",
  "price":"35.00"
}, 
{
    "id": " 14916",
  "asd" : "7947",
    "name": "asd dasd asd ds",
  "label":"ad ad asd a",
  "price":"145.00"
}]
}
```

Comment: Have you checked via the browser console what the *actual* response from the server is?

Comment: Could it be the JSON format is wrong?

Comment: actual response i have pasted

Comment: @Gags your code is failing onError handler and the response in that handler apparently is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @Burimi .. yup i also think that this is the case of Invalid JSON from server :P .. cheers

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned  `dataType: "json"` tat means your js expects the response to be a valid json.
Indeed your json is valid but you also need to set the content type to be json in order for it to be parsed properly.

You need to set the content type header to be application/json.

In php you can use:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```